# Jenkins DSL new view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a DSL plugin file which creates couple of jobs like pipeline, freshly jobs. I wanted to know what would be syntax that i can create different views in this file, Like 5 jobs in 1 view, 5 another jobs in 2 view, I know how to do it using console, but looking forward to update file and it would be automatically created.

Comment: If you refer to Jenkins UI views, I don't think you can do it using Jenkinsfile

Comment: You can do virtually anything in groovy in a Jenkinsfile. I don't know the objects to use to do it, but if you look in that direction, I'm sure you can find something.

Comment: yes looks good. https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/listView

Comment: JobDSL is not (Pipelines = Jenkinsfile).

Comment: Yes, But I used syntax and same worked in my jenkinsfile

Comment: You was correct @StephenKing it was actually DSL one. I have edited my question

Comment: ... and kept the wrong tag

Answer (score 1):

worked fine as used groovy syntax

```
listView('testlist') {
description('All new jobs for testlist')
filterBuildQueue()
filterExecutors()
jobs {
    name('fruit') 
    name('cake') 

}
    columns {
    status()
    weather()
    name()
    lastSuccess()
    lastFailure()
    lastDuration()
    buildButton()
}
```

}